# Performance issues when merging large files into one single file

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline contains multiple copy activity, and the main purpose of these activities is to merge multiples files into one single file.
the problem of this pipeline is, it takes about 4 hours to executes (to merge the files).is there any way to reduce the duration please.

thanks for your reply .

Comment: Indexed lcompressed ines, other disk, RAM usage (buffer size), a couple of threads,, careful concurrency/queueing. Reading binary bytes (no UTF-8 conversion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the copy operation is being performed on an Azure integration
   runtime, the following steps must be followed:

   For Data Integration Units (DIU) and parallel copy settings, start with the
   default values.
2. If you're using a self-hosted integration runtime, you'll need to do
   the following:

   Would recommend that you run IR on a separate computer. The machine should
   be kept isolated from the data store server. Start using the default
   defaults for parallel copy settings and the self-hosted IR on a single
   node.

Else you may leverage:

1. A Data Integration Unit (DIU)

It is a measure that represents the power of a single unit in Azure Data Factory and Synapse pipelines. Power is a combination of CPU, memory, and network resource allocation. DIU only applies to Azure integration runtime. DIU does not apply to self-hosted integration runtime.

2. Parallel Copy

Could set the parallel Copies property to indicate the parallelism you want the copy activity to use. Think of this property as the maximum number of threads within the copy activity. The threads operate in parallel. The threads either read from your source, or write to your sink data stores.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-troubleshooting), is the MSFT Document to Troubleshoot copy activity performance.

> When copying data into Azure Table, default parallel copy is 4.he
> range of DIU setting is 2-256.However, specific behaviors of DIU in
> different copy scenarios are different even though you set the number
> as you want.

Please see the table list here,especially for the below part

[image]

DIU has some limitations as you seen,so you could choose the optimal setting with your custom scenario.

If you are trying to copy 1GB data, thus somehow DIU never crossed 4.

But when If you try to copy 10GB data, then you could notice DIU started scaling up beyond 4.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-features#data-integration-units) is the list of the Data Integration Units.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the upvote :)  @Java User, could you please accept the answer so as it would be beneficial for other community members and to the question shall stand answered.

Comment: thanks for your reply, actually I'm using the default integration run time ti execute my pipeline, which is better the default run time or self-hosted integration runtime ?

Comment: Azure Integration Runtime is managed by Microsoft. All the patching, scaling and maintenance of the underlying infrastructure is taken care of. The IR can only access data stores and services in public networks where as A self-hosted integration runtime can run copy activities between a cloud data store and a data store in a private network. --- Depends on your need.

Comment: thanks for these informations, I will keep using the default run time, can you help me please to define the values which I should give to DIU and Copy parallelism please ?

Comment: yes that could be set inside Copy Activity according to your need, Could not be able to help with exact number as am not aware of your configuration, for now you could start having it low- else you can increase it.

Comment: by default it indicated auto in DIU and nothing on parallel copy, and when I see the monitor I fount that there is 4 DIU used and 1 parallel copy

Comment: Please check the last part of my answer - as I have updated it.

Comment: Yes understood, so now I need to use 6 or 7 at the UID and then test ?

Comment: Yes but has the units in a order of 2,4, 8 and so on. As I updated in the Answer, while you configure the copy activity in the `settings`

Comment: what about the copy parallelism, should I increased too ?

Comment: No not as of now, Thank you so much :)   - would request you to go through that link so you would have a lot clear ideas to choose https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-troubleshooting

Comment: thank you it is clear ;)

Comment: Awesome!! Happy Learning :)